# I have installed express and express-generator but still its not working however i can see both the folders in node_modules

Tags: express, mean-stack

After installing express and express-generator I am not able to use 'express' keyword.

Tried this command

```
npm install express
```

and

```
npm install express-generator
```

```
cmd> express --v
```

when checking `express --v` in cmd it should display installed version but i am getting the below error.

> express : The term 'express' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
>   the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + express --v
>   + ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (express:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able to use express in terminal , you need to install the package globally.

```
npm i -g express
express
```

if you don't install it globally then you can access it only within your project scope from package.json scripts.

for reference checkout the link ->  https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts